# The reasons for changes in Tefilah when Rosh Hasahana falls on Shabbat

Tags: tefilla, shabbat, rosh-hashanah-new-year

I have summarized some changes in the Rosh Hashanah Tefilah that falls on Shabbat and I would be happy to understand whether the change took place and the reason for the change in the wording (Ashkenazi, Sfard Nusach):

- A. Lecha Dodi - do they say in the last Bayit (stanza) - Berina Ubetzhala or Gam besimcha Ubetzhala ? According to the Rinat Yisrael Machzor of Rosh Hashanah - only Berina is mentioned, while on other Yom Tovs that fall on Shabbat they say Besimcha ?
- B. Will the person who eats garlic on Shabbat eve (which is spicy) continue to do so on Shabbat eve on which Rosh Hashanah falls (who usually do not eat spicy things)?
- C. It is well known that the acronym Shabbat sleep on Shabbat is a pleasure and it is customary to sleep on Shabbat. On Rosh Hashanah it is customary not to sleep so that one's luck does not sleep. How can one behave on Rosh Hashanah that falls on Shabbat?
- D. At the Rosh Hashanah offering, which begins to be on Shabbat, when scrolling the Torah at Mincha, do we say the psalms chapters 111  and 112 of the Psalms. In the Rinat Yisrael Machzor for Rosh Hashanah it does not appear that way.
- E. Do we say before the meals as in every Shabbat Atkino Saudta, etc.?

Comment: Ashkis don't sing lecha dodi on Shabbos Rosh Hashono? They start from mizmor shir.

Comment: How do B and C (and maybe also E) relate to tefillah?

Comment: @Dov Ashkenazim who use “nusach sefard” recite an abridged version of lecha dodi if yom tov falls on shabbat or erev shabbat (and on shabbat chol hamoed)